# Why is there no Server Fault Twitter account?

Tags: discussion

Why serverfault don't have a twitter account, which twit about most recent or "Hot" Questions?

Other communities , like unix.stackexchange.com , have their twitter accounts to do that.
I think that will help to increase our community.

Comment: What's Twitter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, but it does, if you [check the site directory](http://stackexchange.com/sites) and look for the twitter icon.

[image]

See http://twitter.com/ServerFault

Comment: My fault, sorry

Comment: that's OK, there's no way for you to know about it other than checking the site directory. And it is also new.. we only set it up about a week ago!

Comment: And what if you do a link to SFaul's twitter account somewhere in the left column? Will be more easy to find

Answer (score 3):

Who needs twitter?  All the cool sysadmins are constantly on SF and chat, hitting refresh endlessly, like a chipmunk on speed.

Comment: More like [Max Zorin with an `indispensable` computer](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=043WEs_6TAo)